# How to change the texture of player entity when it jumps in Ursina Engine using Python?

Tags: python, ursina

So I have a 2d Platformer Controller in my game, called Jared. There he is:
[image]

But I want his face to change when he jumps, I'll design a new picture of Jared when he jumps.

But how can I actually to it? I tried this but It didn't work...,

```
def input(key):
    if key == 'space':
        player.set_texture(panda3d.core.Texture('new_jared.png'))
```

I'm kinda new. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`player.texture = 'new_jared'`

This is covered in the documentation: https://www.ursinaengine.org/entity_basics.html